# Is github.com/Visual-Studio-Code the legitimate owner for using GitHub OAuth authentication in VSCode?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, malware

I installed VSCode on a new device today and signed in with GitHub authentication. I happened to review my Authorized OAuth Apps in Github and noticed the GitHub for VS Code application entry says its owned by `Visual-Studio-Code` and connects to `github.com/Visual-Studio-Code` rather than the `github.com/microsoft/vscode`. Is this expected, or is something fishy going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On https://github.com/Visual-Studio-Code, that GitHub organization has the [verified badge](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/organizations/managing-organization-settings/verifying-or-approving-a-domain-for-your-organization) for code.visualstudio.com. And I recognize the names of some of the members from seeing them handling issue tickets in the VS Code repo. Indeed, [all those people shown as members of that organization work on the VS Code team](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/graphs/contributors).

See also [Visual-Studio-Code organization owns first party authentication but looks very sketchy #158980](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/158980), where [TylerLeonhardt said](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/158980#issuecomment-1228753688):

> The root of the problem is
>
> - we don't wanna move the GitHub for VS Code app under the Microsoft org because that org is huge and not owned by the vscode team
> - we don't wanna move microsoft/vscode to Visual-Studio-Code/vscode as that looks silly...
> - GH doesn't have a way to have an app assigned to a specific repo

Apparently there are more members of the VS Code team in that GitHub organization whose membership is just not public ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/158980#issuecomment-1230850514)).

For your reference / learning purposes, I found that issue ticket by searching "[`"github.com/Visual-Studio-Code"`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/search?q=%22github.com%2FVisual-Studio-Code%22&type=issues)" in the `microsoft/vscode` repo's search bar.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Also, its good to see I wasn't the only one caught off guard by it.